# Reorder XML Nodes - Java DOM Parser

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, domparser

I am trying to reorder nodes, but for some reason, the result is not correct.

Condition:

- Number of elements in person = someNodeList.size()
- Elements in the list denote the position of the selected nodes in XML, where the integer value of the element in the list is never greater than the total number of nodes in XML.
- The nodes to be moved are already selected

Here is the sample example

```
<start>
    <Item>
        <CodeName attr="Name">
            <Value>Sam</Value>
        </CodeName>
        <CodeName attr="Name">
            <Value>Liam</Value>
        </CodeName>
        <CodeName attr="Name">
            <Value>Joe</Value>
        </CodeName>
        <CodeName attr="Name">
            <Value>Noah</Value>
        </CodeName>
        <CodeName attr="Name">
            <Value>Kris</Value>
        </CodeName>
        <CodeName attr="Name">
            <Value>Jems</Value>
        </CodeName>
    </Item>
</start>
```

Initial ordered

1. Sam
2. Liam
3. Joe
4. Noah
5. Kris
6. Jems

The only nodes I am changing is the node containing the value Jems to position 2, Noah to position 5 and Sam to position 4. Other value can rearrange itself. I just need these 3 nodes to move to the given position.
if I pass value as {2,4,5},
then it should be

1. //any node besides the three selected (Jems, Sam, Noah)
2. Jems
3. //any node besides the three selected (Jems, Sam, Noah)
4. Sam
5. Noah
6. //any node besides the three selected (Jems, Sam, Noah)

   Liam
            
            
                Jems
            
            
                Joe
            
            
                Sam
            
            
                Noah
            
            
                Kris

Here is my loop:

```
List<Integer> position = Arrays.asList(2, 4, 5);

for(int x=0;x<someNodeList.size()-1;x>=0;x--){
    Node oldNode = someNodeList.get(x).getParentNode().getParentNode();
    Node parentNode = oldNode.getParentNode();

    Nodelist someOtherNodeList = ((Element) parentNode).getElementsByTagName("Price");

    parentNode.insertBefore(oldNode,someOtherNodeList.item(position.get(x));
}
```

The output position came to be 3,4,5. But this works perfectly fine if I am to reorder only two nodes. How do I get consistent results if I am to re-order any number of nodes?